# Degenerate AABB (axis aligned bounding box), does this always intersect?

Tags: 3d, aabb, raytracing

I'm studying ray-AABB intersections and I'm asking myself: what would happen if one of the dimensions of the axis aligned bounding box was degenerated?

For instance:

```
AABB_min = {1,1,1}
AABB_max = {5,5,1}
```

in this case the Z coordinate would be the same for the AABB maximum and minimum point. You can think of this AABB as a 2D rectangle.

In such a case, would this always yield "true" as intersection with a ray if the ray's Tmax and Tmin were something like *+inf* and *-inf* (so that we don't need to bother with them)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. It's trivial to see that a 2D ray doesn't necessarily intersect a 2D rectangle.

Comment: 3D ray, and for @concept3d I was referring to this algorithm: http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-7-intersecting-simple-shapes/ray-box-intersection/

Comment: @DavidKernin I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided is not a degenerate case, and it works. This will give correct results. You didn't mention which algorithm you are talking about but I assume you're talking about the <del>SLABS method (correct me if I am wrong)</del>.

The OP was talking about [this paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/amy/papers/box-jgt.pdf), which is similar to the slabs method and my explanation almost remains the same.

<del>I don't know why you assume `Tmin` and `Tmax` will be +/-inf, they will simply be equal for the z coordinates, in other words `TminZ = TmaxZ`. Keep in mind that for `Tmin`, `Tmax` to make sense they are calculated for each axis independently.</del>

The case is valid for Tmin and Tmax being +/-infinity the quote from the paper.

> Note that the reason we check the sign of each component direction is
>   to ensure that the intervals produced are ordered (i.e., so that tmin
>   <= tmax is true). This property is assumed throughout the code, and
>   allows us to reason about whether the computed intervals overlap. Note
>   also that since IEEE arithmetic guarantees that a positive number
>   divided by zero is +1 and a negative number divided by zero is ¡1, the
>   code works for vertical and horizontal lines (see [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) for a detailed
>   discussion of this)

Note that your degenerate case was not when Zmin = Zmax. your missing point was when a ray is parallel to a certain axis which could yield `Tz = +/-inf`.

If you have a case where the bounding box `min > max` then this is not an AABB, and according to the algorithm it doesn't apply since `max>min` is a pre-condition for any ray/AABB algorithm; that input is undefined for that certain algorithm.

Moreover any anlytical or algebraic solution should define the [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of the problem (domain as in mathematics) on the input, otherwise running that solution on that input is undefined. And the example you provided is defined for that particular algorithm.